# Ajax - php echo statements not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm developing a ajax-php event calendar and in the form to Add events I have ajax:

```
function PostData() {

                var xhr;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                else {
                    throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
                }
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                        if (xhr.status == 200 ){//&& xhr.status < 300) {
                            if(xhr.responseText == 1){
                                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "SUCCESS";
                               //window.location = "form2.php";
                            }
                            else{
                                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                var a = document.getElementById("aaa").value;
                var b = document.getElementById("bbb").value;
                var c = document.getElementById("ccc").value;

                xhr.open('POST', 'addEvent.php');
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhr.send("xxx=" + a+"&yyy="+b+"&zzz="+c);
}
        </script>`:
```

and my server side php code that should echo the result of the adding Events, such as successful or database error or so :

```
  <?php
include ("connect.php");
$eventDate = $_POST["xxx"];
$eventTime = $_POST["yyy"];
$eventDesc = $_POST["zzz"];

if($eventDate != '' && $eventDesc != '' && $eventTime != ''){
   // $timestamp = strtotime($eventTime);
    //$eventTime =  date("H:i", $timestamp);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO events(evdate,evtime,evdesc,username) VALUES ('$eventDate','$eventTime','$eventDesc','usr')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
        echo 1;
    else 
        echo mysqli_error();
}
else
    echo 'you must not leave it blank';

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

As the output, in case there were fields that were unfilled in the Event adding form the echo statement at the bottom of the php file works. But in case a row was inserted the echo statement does not work. Also if there is an error in inserting a record, still it doesn't work.

Comment: `if(condition) { //statements }else{  //echo }`

Comment: Look at the actual response in the Network tab of the Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
    echo 1;
else 
    echo mysqli_error($conn); // required connection parameter here...
```

Comment: That explains why the error case doesn't work, but he said he also doesn't get `1` when the insert is successful.

Comment: because there is parse error in script: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given.

Comment: Wrong number of arguments isn't a parse error, it's a runtime warning. It only happens when you try to execute the statement, not when the script is being parsed.